# Converting terminal CURL to PHP CURL?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

How would I submit this `test.xml` file in PHP using this `CURL` command:

```
 curl -X POST -k -d @test.xml -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --user username:password https://www.url.com
```

This isn't working for me:

```
 $ch = curl_init();

 //Get the response from cURL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 //Set the Url
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://username:password@url.com');

 //Create a POST array with the file in it
 $postData = array(
'testData' => '@test.xml',
 );
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

 // Execute the request
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I'm also wondering how I could submit XML written in the code instead of an XML file.

Comment: dont put username\password in the url

Comment: is that the only thing wrong in my code? and how would I pass the username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put username and password in the url. You can use `curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);` for `$username` and `$password`. Eg below:

```
$p = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($p, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($p);
curl_close($p);
```